# Dynamic method call in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm aware that I could do this:

```
var myClass = { /* my class definition */ };
var methodName = 'myMethod';
myClass[methodName](p1,p2,...,pN);
```

But what should I do if have this:

```
if(data.someMethodName[0]!== undefined){ ... }
```

or

```
data.someMethodName[i].someAttribute
```

How do I call `someMethodName` dynamically meaning calling it as a string?

Comment: Exactly the same way. Which is `data[someMethodName]()` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Also that's not a "method call", it's a "property access".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the bracket notation:

```
data[someMethodName][0].

data[ someMethodName[0] ](p1, p2, ...)
```

Comment: `data.someMethodName[i].someAttribute` how do I call this?

Comment: @Alan: Your example really isn't clear. Please be more specific.

Comment: `data[someMethodName][0]` and `data[ someMethodName[0] ]` are not the same. are you sure it should be so?

Comment: @FelixKling, I showed 2 examples of what I wanted to know about. What was not clear?

Comment: @Alan: Whether `someMethodName` is a string or an array. Whether you want to call a method with the name contained in `someMethodName[0]` or `someMethodName`. What `someAttribute` is. Etc. But apart from that, it's always the same. Whenever you have an invalid identifier name or a variable, you have to use bracket notation instead of dot notation.

Comment: someAttribute is a attribute. someMethodName[0 | i] is an array I want to call dynamically.

Comment: @Alan: So, is `data[someMethodName[i]]().someAttribute` what you want? It's still confusing. A concrete example, with actual values, would really help.

Comment: `data.someMethodName[i].someAttribute`, if both someMethodName and someAttribute are variables, can be written as `data[ someMethodName ][ someAttribute ] = "new value"`