# jquery dynamic .append | .prepend | .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I have some html I would like to either `.prepend`, `.append`, or `.html` it into a container div.

Currenty I have

```
$.globalEval('$("#target").'+ method + '(html)'
```

which is eval'd to the likes of

```
$('#target').append(html)
```

or

```
$('#target').prepend(html)
```

or

```
$('#target').html(html)
```

but I feel dirty when resorting to `eval`. Is there an alternate?

Comment: What case needs to be fulfilled for each to be used?

Comment: try `window[method]` in place of `method`

Comment: There should definitely be a cleaner way out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic method call in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984376/dynamic-method-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without eval :

```
$("#target")[method](html)
```

This uses the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to dynamically access the property of the `$("#target")` object.